# How to let the cell E2 be the worksheet name in the macro code?

Tags: vba, excel

This is a brief description..
1) The sheet name of workbook 2 is not known yet
2) The user would then write the sheet name in workbook1 sheet1 Cell E2

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("")
```

From here, the macro must be able to detect the worksheet name in  Cell E2 in workbook1 and paste it in the workbook1 (sheet:???) below without manually keying in.

```
    x.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Columns("B").CopyDestination:=y.Sheets("???").Range("B" &Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: It maybe morning here and maybe my mind isn't ready, but I almost didn't understand any part of what you are asking... You want to copy a range of data containing E2 and then rename the worksheet to E2 value?

Comment: `sheetName = [E2]: Workbooks("otherWorkbook").Sheets(sheetName).Activate`

Answer (score 0):

It *appears* to me that you want:

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks.Open("")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("")
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Columns("B").Copy Destination:=y.Sheets(x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value).Range("B" &Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Comment: nope. What i want is the value in Cell E2 would be the sheet name .

Comment: x.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Columns("B").CopyDestination:=y.Sheets("The sheet name that is in Cell E2").Range("B" &Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: E2 of which sheet? The code I posted uses E2 on Sheet1 of workbook x, which is what you asked for.